# Economics Marginal Cost and Average Cost

Tags: average

I am in Computer Engineering but this year the university gave me choice for two electives with one being Psychology and the other Economics...So this being my first economics course I am really stumped! It doesn't really make much sense to me so I am asking for help here. The below is the 2nd last question from an assignment. How do I even start this? I am not even sure I will find someone with economics knowledge here but I will try anyway.

[image]

Comment: what is Qu in this context

Comment: q is usually quantity in this course. Qu I don't know but I know q is quantity.